# Mutually Commutative Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, terminology, commutator

What is the definition of a mutually commutative set of operators? I've found articles describing a complete set of mutually commutative operators, but I can't actually find what mutually commutative means. I ask because I'm asked to prove that a particular set of operators is mutually commutative.

Comment: It means they all commute with one another.

Comment: If $\{A_1,\ldots, A_n\}$ is your set then $[A_i,A_j]=0\forall i,j$.

Answer (score 2):

A pair of selfadjoint operators $A : D(A) \to H$, $B: D(B) \to H$, where $D(A),D(B) \subset H$ are dense subspaces of the Hilbert space $H$, are said to **commute** if the *spectral measures* of $A$ and $B$ commute:
$$P^{(A)}_E P_F^{(B)}= P_F^{(B)}P^{(A)}_E \quad \mbox{for every pair of Borel sets $E, F \subset \mathbb{R}$.}\tag{1}$$
The *spectral measures* (or PVMs) are uniquely determined by the *spectral decomposition* of $A$ and $B$:
$$A = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda dP^{(A)}(\lambda)\:, \quad B = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lambda dP^{(B)}(\lambda)\:.$$
Condition (1) for $A$, $B$ selfadjoint, with the said domains, is separately equivalent to each of the  following requirments
$$e^{itA}e^{isB}= e^{isB}e^{itA} \quad \forall s,t \in \mathbb{R}\:,$$
$$e^{itA}B x= Be^{itA}x \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R},\quad  \forall x \in D(B)$$
$$P^{(A)}_E Bx = BP^{(A)}_Ex\quad \forall x \in D(B), \forall E \subset \mathbb{R} \mbox{$\quad$ Borel.}$$
If $A,B \in \mathfrak{B}(H)$  (the $C^*$-algebra of the bounbed everywhere defined operators in $H$) are selfadjoint, in particular if $H$ is finite dimensional,  then (1) is equivalent to
$$AB=BA\tag{2}\:.$$
If $A^*=A\in  \mathfrak{B}(H)$ and $B=B^*$ is generally unbounded, then (1) is equivalent to
$$ABx = BAx \quad \forall x \in D(B)\:.$$

Let us come to the notion of **complete set of mutually commuting observables** also known as **maximal set of mutually compatible observables** with obvious variations of the words compatible, commuting, observables, selfadjoint operators.

Let us assume that $H$ is separable.

Consider a (finite) set of mutually commuting observables (selfadjoint operators)  ${\cal A}:= \{ A_1,\ldots, A_N\}$, so that their spectral measures pairwise commute. In this case it is possible to define a **joint spectral measure** $P$ defined on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^N$, it is uniquely defined from the requirement  that
$$A_k = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lambda_k dP(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_N)\quad k = 1,\ldots, N\:.$$
${\cal A}$ is said to be **complete** or **maximal** if every (bounded) observable ($B =B^*  \in \mathfrak{B}(H)$) which commutes with all $A_k$ is a (bounded) *function of these operators*:
$$B =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_N) dP(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_N)$$
for some (bounded Borel measurable) function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$.

It is not difficult to prove the following fact  if all operators $A_k$ have *point spectrum* $\sigma_p(A_k)= \sigma(A)$ (in particular $H$ is finite dimensional).

Let us define $H^{(A_k)}_{\lambda_k}$ the eigenspace of $A_k$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_k \in \sigma(A_k)$.

*If ${\cal A}$ is a maximal set of mutually commuting observables then,
for every choice of the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_N$,
the intersection of $H^{(A_1)}_{\lambda_1}, \ldots,H^{(A_N)}_{\lambda_N}$ is at most one-dimensional.*

(Also the converse fact is true, always referring to a set of mutually commuting selfadjoint operators with point spectrum).

From a physical perspective,  all that implies in particular that
one may "prepare the states" just by measuring a maximal set of commuting observables with point spectrum.
Indeed, if one measures all the observables $A_k$ (with point spectrum) on an initial state vector $\Psi$, the *post measurement unit vector  state* $\Psi_{\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_N}$
is completely fixed (up to a phase as usual) by the sequence of the outcomes $\lambda_1 \in \sigma(A_1),\ldots, \lambda_N \in \sigma(A_N)$.

In the more sophisticated approach based on the notion of von Neumann algebra,
a (finite) set of mutually commuting observables (selfadjoint operators)  ${\cal A}:= \{ A_1,\ldots, A_N\}$ is said to be  **maximal** if the *commutant* $\mathfrak{R}'$ of the  von Neumann  algebra $\mathfrak{R}$ *generated* by ${\cal A}$ (*) is included in $\mathfrak{R}$ itself: $\mathfrak{R}' \subset \mathfrak{R}$.
The generated von Neumann algebra (in this case of $H$ separable) turns out to be
the family of (complex) maps
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_N) dP(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_N)$$
for some (Borel measurable) bounded function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{C}$. Therfore this definition is equivalent to the one stated above.

From a physical point of view, the existence of a maximal set of commuting observables is not always guaranteed. It exists referring to elementary systems, but there are important cases where it cannot exist (**). It happens for instance if the physical system admits a *non-Abelian gauge group* (think of chromodynamics where the group is $SU(3)$ color). In that case one cannot "prepare" the states.

---

(*) That is, by definition, the family of bounded operators which commute with all bounded operators which commute with all elements $P^{(A_k)}_E$ of the spectral measures of the selfadjoint operators in ${\cal A}$. Equivalently, this family is the *weak closure* of the set of linear combinations of those operators $P^{(A_k)}_E$.

(**) Here is the reason. (I use standard properties of von Neumann algebras). Suppose that the von Neumann algebra of observables $\mathfrak{R}$ of a certain physical system admits a maximal set of mutually commuting observables ${\cal A}$.  Hence ${\cal A} \subset \mathfrak{R}$ so that, since  ${\cal A}' \subset {\cal A}''$  by definition of ${\cal A}$, we have
$$\mathfrak{R}' \subset {\cal A}' \subset {\cal A}'' \subset \mathfrak{R}'' = \mathfrak{R}\:.$$
This implies in particular that $\mathfrak{R}' \subset \mathfrak{R}$ and thus
$\mathfrak{R}' = \mathfrak{R}\cap \mathfrak{R}'$. Hence the commutant $\mathfrak{R}'$ of the algebra of observables must be Abelian since it coincides with the center of the algebra $ \mathfrak{R}\cap \mathfrak{R}'$. This is not possible if the commutant includes non commuting selfadjoint operators  as it happens if there is a gauge group which is non-Abelian and faithfully acts. The non-commuting selfadjoint operators are the selfadjoint generators of the representation of the group in the Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0):

Mutually commutative means that every operator in the set commutes with every other one. This implies that, if the operators in question are observables, they can all be measured simultaneously.

A complete set of mutually commuting observables is a set of observable, hermitian operators that commute - therefore their eigenvalues can be used to label a state. "Complete" refers to the state being fully determined without degeneracies.

As an example: The most famous set are the quantum numbers labeling the Hydrogen orbitals, corresponding to the set of observables
$$ {\mathcal H, \vec J^2, J_z, \vec L^2, \vec S^2}$$
With the five eigenvalues of these operators the state of the electron in the hydrogen atom can be uniquely determined and all these values *can* be measured simultaneously because every operator in the set commutes with all others.

Comment: Another example: if the operators are generators, and they all mutually commute, they form a Cartan subalgebra.

Comment: I'm not sure that your definition of "complete" is the correct one. A set $F$ of pair-wise self-adjoint operators from an Abelian von Neumann algebra $M$ is complete if every other element in $M$ is an $L^\infty$ function of the elements in $F$ and every function in $L^\infty$ of the elements in $F$ gives an element in $M$. Such $M$ usually arises as the bicommutant of some commutative C*-algebra of observables.